# Rails 4 - Sending Google Maps API JSON return val to controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I'm using Google Maps JavaScript API to return the distance from point A to Point B and I'm successfully able to get the value. I'm also able to see it by writing it to the log (Using Google Chrome DevTools) using the following JS:

```
console.log(totalDistance);
```

What I've tried so far has not worked so far which is to have a hidden tag and set the value of it using JS:

```
$('#distance').text(totalDistance);
```

In the view the form I have is:

```
<%= form_tag({ :action => 'fare', :controller=> 'page'}, {:class => 'form-horizontal center'}) do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :origin, '', class: 'form-control', id: 'origin-input' %><br/>
   <%= text_field_tag :destination, '', class: 'form-control', id: 'destination-input' %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :distance, '', id: 'distance' %>
   <%= submit_tag "Submit" , id: 'get-route'%><!-- the id is needed for the JS -->
<% end %>
```

My thought was to pass the value over as a parameter to the controller so I'm checking the params that are passed over through my view like this:

```
<pre>
<% params.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= key + "==>" + value + "\n" %>
<% end %>
</pre>
```

The output is as such:

```
    utf8==>✓

    authenticity_token==>**omitted**

    origin==>LaGuardia Airport, NY, United States

    destination==>JFK Airport, NY, United States

    distance==>

    commit==>Submit

    controller==>page

    action==>fare
```

But as you can see the parameter **'distance'** does not have a value that goes over to the controller. **But I do see the value of the totalDistance in my log**

**So What I really need help with is figuring out what should be in action of my controller, if my javascript needs to be changed to something else and in my view if I should change anything. I feel I'm not doing this correctly. 



One thing I have noticed is when I was trying different things, I was trying to set a div with an id of "distance" to the value of totalDistance and when I would hit submit on my form, the div would show the correct distance and, since I have the page just reloading right now, the value would not stay once the page reloaded.**

I do know how to assign instance variables in my controller from parameters already and also accessing them in my view. That is not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hidden input field. Then you might want to use

```
$('#distance').val(totalDistance)
```

As, you are trying to assign text; which might not work. And, you have to use .val() to set/get value for input fields.

refer:

1. http://api.jquery.com/val/
2. http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: This is a valuable answer that will help but I'm afraid in this situation it hasn't helped my issue. What would be the steps to take on the controller side in my action?

Comment: Can you inspect the params that are passed to the controller. In that way, you can check, what value was passed in which field. And then in the controller, get the has value accordingly. `params['something']`

Comment: I've updated my question to better show what I have. I am able to access the params and assign them to instance variables already with the two input fields I have and then see those in my view as well perfectly fine. The other params are passing fine.